# How to Add a splitView within a splitView in Android(Multi-View Panes)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

[image: splitView within splitView]

I would like to implement a splitView based on the logic relayed in the image shown in Android.

Is it possible to actually do this?  If so, could anyone please advise on how I should proceed preferably with an example?

Thanks alot.

Comment: Lalit The question is completely different as it defines two splitViews while my question is related to having a three splitViews with one being inside another

Comment: For using split view better use Fragment , separate jar file is provided by android to support fragments in lower version also.

Comment: I know all this, my question is how can I implement the concept in the image above?

Comment: Any thoughts anyone?? I am in dire need!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for xml layout.. 
         `

```
       <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

       <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#234567" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:background="#ffffff"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:weightSum="2" >

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#234545"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#234567" />
      </LinearLayout>

      <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#235656"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#234567" />
      </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>

      </LinearLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will do what you want use below Layout file and on click of

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/root"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/base"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

1. Second Button change `orientation` of root to `vertical` and base to `horizontal`.
2. First button reverse the changes that will make such a `layout`

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to use Fragments. While they are new in Honeycomb, the Android Compatibility Package supports them all the way back to api level 4. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Thanks but I am aware of this. I only require some code to show how this can be implemented..

Answer (score 0):

This can be one solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0px"
            android:layout_weight=".25" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

But Layout weights require a widget to be measured twice. When a LinearLayout with non-zero weights is nested inside another LinearLayout with non-zero weights, then the number of measurements increase exponentially.

Also check this [link](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html)  for some alternatives using relative layout . But you can not use weights in relative layout.